# Summary Rollup: To many SQOL

Tags: trigger, soql, error

I'm using [Anthony Victorio's roll-up summary fields utility](http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/) for a client.
I did some testing as it was shown on his site and the utility works really nice. A couple of days ago I was working on some test classes that are somehow connected to the operations executed by Anthony's roll-up utility.

After setting up the data needed for my test and fixing so issues I was facing the **too many SOQL: 101 error**. The strange thing is that it was coming from Anthony's utility. More specific on these lines:

```
for(sObject s : Database.query(parentQuery))
    {

        Integer row = 0; //row counter reset for every parent record
        for(fieldDefinition d : fieldDefinitions)
        {
            String field = 'expr' + row.format();
            AggregateResult r = parentValueMap.get(s.Id);
            //r will be null if no records exist 
            //(e.g. last record deleted)
            if(r != null) { 
                Decimal value = ((Decimal)r.get(field) == null ) ? 0 : 
                    (Decimal)r.get(field);
                s.put(d.parentField, value);
            } else {
                s.put(d.parentField, 0);
            }
            row += 1; //plus 1 for every field definition after first
        }
        parentsToUpdate.add(s);
    }
```

I tried several things to get rid of this error but I just can't figure out what can be causing this or how to fix it. 
So my question is, there is a way I can bulkify this part of the code better in order to remove this issue? 
There is a way to improve it? Kindly let me know if you do.

**This is the utility:**

```
public class RollUpSummaryUtility {

//the following class will be used to house the field names
//and desired operations
public class fieldDefinition {
    public String operation {get;set;}
    public String childField {get;set;}
    public String parentField {get;set;}

    public fieldDefinition (String o, String c, String p) {
        operation = o;
        childField = c;
        parentField = p;
    }
}

public static void rollUpTrigger(list<fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions,
list<sObject> records, String childObject, String childParentLookupField, 
String parentObject, String queryFilter)
{

    //Limit the size of list by using Sets which do not contain duplicate
    //elements prevents hitting governor limits
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();

    for(sObject s : records)
    {
        parentIds.add((Id)s.get(childParentLookupField));
    }

    //populate query text strings to be used in child aggregrator and 
    //parent value assignment
    String fieldsToAggregate = '';
    String parentFields = '';

    for(fieldDefinition d : fieldDefinitions)
    {
        fieldsToAggregate += d.operation + '(' + d.childField + ') ' + 
        ', ';
        parentFields += d.parentField + ', ';
    }

    //Using dynamic SOQL with aggergate results to populate parentValueMap
    String aggregateQuery = 'Select ' + fieldsToAggregate + 
    childParentLookupField + ' from ' + childObject + ' where  ' + 
    childParentLookupField + ' IN :parentIds ' + queryFilter + ' ' +
    ' group by ' + childParentLookupField;

    //Map will contain one parent record Id per one aggregate object
    map<Id, AggregateResult> parentValueMap = 
    new map <Id, AggregateResult>();

    for(AggregateResult q : Database.query(aggregateQuery))
    {
        parentValueMap.put((Id)q.get(childParentLookupField), q);
    }

    //list of parent object records to update
    list<sObject> parentsToUpdate = new list<sObject>();

    String parentQuery = 'select ' + parentFields + ' Id ' +
     ' from ' + parentObject + ' where Id IN :parentIds';

    //for each affected parent object, retrieve aggregate results and 
    //for each field definition add aggregate value to parent field
    for(sObject s : Database.query(parentQuery))
    {

        Integer row = 0; //row counter reset for every parent record
        for(fieldDefinition d : fieldDefinitions)
        {
            String field = 'expr' + row.format();
            AggregateResult r = parentValueMap.get(s.Id);
            //r will be null if no records exist 
            //(e.g. last record deleted)
            if(r != null) { 
                Decimal value = ((Decimal)r.get(field) == null ) ? 0 : 
                    (Decimal)r.get(field);
                s.put(d.parentField, value);
            } else {
                s.put(d.parentField, 0);
            }
            row += 1; //plus 1 for every field definition after first
        }
        parentsToUpdate.add(s);
    }

    //if parent records exist, perform update of all parent records 
    //with a single DML statement
    if(parentsToUpdate.Size() > 0)
    {
        update parentsToUpdate;
    }

  }

}
```

Exact Error:

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Comment: I didn't go through the code a ton, but as long as you're not querying in a loop you're fine.. Remember this SOQL limit error is an aggregate of queries in the execution so this may not be the trigger you need to look at.